# take multiple images into single image asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, image

Is there a way of taking 3 images and combinging them into one image. I would like to do this and share on facebook and other social sites. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: If you truly need to combine them into 1 binary image instead of CSS solution posted below - look into GDI+ implementation in ASP.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by placing the the images in a div that has further three divs. And make the child divs style block:inline. Assign border to each div. You task is done!

Set width and height you like. and this should be the same height and width as the image

```
<style>
.image{
 display:inline
}
</style>

<div id="threeImages">
<div id="imageOne" class="image"><img src="img1.jpg" /></div>
<div id="imageTwo" class="image"><img src="img2.jpg" /></div>
<div id="imageThree" class="image"><img src="img3.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you need to facebook, sorry i have no experience doing any facebook task, but I know facebook uses iFrame. So you can do this somewhere and on your facebook app, you can refer to the iFrame